# Insert if exists

Tags: mysql, t-sql

I have two tables: second table have foreign key, that references primary key of the first table. And when I insert data in the second table, I want to check first, if a row with iputed key exists in the first table. In T-SQL it would look like this:

```
create procedure insert_order_products
@ order_id int
@ product_id int
AS
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM order where order.id=order_id)
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM product where product.id=product_id)
INSERT INTO order_products values(some values)
```

How to check `IF EXISTS` in mysql?

Answer (score 1):

I think you can try to use the following query (`INSERT` with `SELECT` and `WHERE`)

```
INSERT order_products(col1,col2,...,colN)
SELECT @val1,@val2,...,@valN
WHERE EXISTS(SELECT * FROM order WHERE id=@order_id)
  AND EXISTS(SELECT * FROM product WHERE id=@product_id)
```

In MySQL I think it'll be like following

```
INSERT order_products(col1,col2,...,colN)
SELECT @val1,@val2,...,@valN
FROM DUAL
WHERE EXISTS(SELECT * FROM order WHERE id=@order_id)
  AND EXISTS(SELECT * FROM product WHERE id=@product_id)
```

Or you can use

```
INSERT order_products(col1,col2,...,colN)
SELECT @val1,@val2,...,@valN
FROM (SELECT * FROM order WHERE id=@order_id) o
CROSS JOIN (SELECT * FROM product WHERE id=@product_id) p
```

I think the last variant is better.